# How can I choose random indicies based on probability?

Tags: python, probability

I have a list of numbers and I'm trying to write a function that will choose n random indices i such i's likelihood is percentages[i]

Function:

```
def choose_randomly(probabilities, n):
    percentages = accumulated_s(probabilities)
    result = []
    for i in range(n):
        r = random()
        for j in range(n):
            if r < percentages[j]:
                result = result + [j]
    return result
```

accumulated_s will just generate a corresponding list of probabilities.

I'm expecting results like this:

```
choose_randomly([1, 2, 3, 4], 2) -> [3 3 0]
choose_randomly([1, 2, 3, 4], 2) -> [1 3 1]
```

The problem is that this is not returning n indicies. Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong? 
Thank you so much!

Comment: this question has been asked many times. See "Related" in the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you've found the right range of probabilities, you're done; `break` out of the inner loop to generate the next value, or you'll act as if all probabilities above the correct threshold were matched as well:

```
    # Enumerate all percentages, not just first n
    for j, pct in enumerate(percentages):
        if r < pct:
            result.append(j)  # Don't create tons of temporary lists; mutate in place
            break  # <-- Don't add more results
```

Also note, if you have a lot of values in the set of probabilities, it may make sense to use functions from the [`bisect` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html) to find the correct value, rather than scanning linearly each time; for a small number of entries in `percentages`, linear scanning is fine, but for a large number, `O(log n)` lookups may beat `O(n)` scans.

Comment: Thank you so much. Is there any ways to make it generate exactly n indicies though? I edited the code and it works fine, but it does not generate exactly n elements.

Comment: If you `break` correctly in the inner loop, the other loop should cover it. Only reason it wouldn't is if the values in `percentages` were wrong. As written, you'd want ascending cumulative percentages, e.g. `[0.1, 0.3, 0.7, 1.0]`. If it doesn't end with `1.0` or higher, you'd drop data when the random value generated exceeded the highest value in `percentages`.

Comment: Oh, and on rechecking, looks like you were iterating `percentages` wrong (stopping after `n` checks, instead of checking the whole sequence). I've fixed that in my answer (and used `enumerate` so you'd getting values and indices at once to save work).